# Does straw hat and other overheat-slowing items increase heat drain during winter?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

This just hit me as I've been walking around my base during winter − I was still wearing a Straw hat and held a Fancy parasol with 2 yellow Thermal stones in my pocket, but suddenly the screen started freezing way faster than I remember it usually would if I had no gear on, and just 1 Thermal stone.

Does freezing occur faster now, or do the summer items increase heat drain?

Answer (score 2):

No, clothing items such as the straw hat or summer frest have no effect in winter with regards to freezing but any wetness modifier they have will be in effect. They don't make you freeze any faster, it may just seem that way if you usually wear warmth items.